# Entity Framework Core 2.1 wrongly lazy loads some navigation properties but not others

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I'm trying to solve the n+1 problem with my Entity Framework Core 2.1 project by ensuring that I only eager load my models.

The problem I'm having is that some associated models are being lazy loaded, but not others. And to be clear, I don't want anything lazy loaded at all, and I haven't enabled it explicitly. I don't believe this is expected behavior.

For instance, when I run this code the following code, it returns all of the included data as expected.

```
List<User> users = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.Engine)
    .Include(u => u.ClientType)
    .Include(u => u.Organization)
    .Include(u => u.Role)
    .ToList();
```

However, if I remove all of the includes, about 90% of the users in the list will still have it's associated data included. I believe that this is why I'm getting the n+1 problem, despite using eager loading.

Why are only some of the associated models being lazy loaded? Why is anything be lazy loaded when I haven't enabled it? Could this be the root cause of my n+1 problem, despite my efforts to only use eager loading?

Answer (score 1):

EF Core does not enable lazy loading by default.  You have to explicitly opt into it, and then mark your navigation properties as `virtual`. If you don't want lazy loading, make sure your `OnConfiguring` method does not call `UseLazyLoadingProxies()`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
=> optionsBuilder
    // .UseLazyLoadingProxies() <- Only use this to enable lazy loading.
    .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```